# Multicore usage of linux and AUTOSAR

Tags: linux, multicore

As a part of my master thesis, I have to use two operating systems (Linux and AUTOSAR OS) in NXP/Free-scale IMX6 multi-core chip. Linux should run on one core and AUTOSAR OS should run on the other.

1. I have the two executable output files but I am not sure how to load
   these together into the board. As far as I know, I need to modify
   Linux U-boot to flash to the AUTOSAR OS . But I am not sure whether
   it works.

please let me know if anyone has resolved this scenario!

Comment: I never heard about AUTOSAR OS, but, by a quick tour on website, it looks me as a standalone OS. So, it seems difficult to put Linux and AUTOSAR OS on same processor whithout modify it... Take a look at [xenomai](http://xenomai.org/), they use a specific patch (I-Pipe) to use two different kernels (Linux and another one) on same processor - It can give you example to how to achieve what you want. But they are doing a lot of work from long time on both kernels to achieve this

Comment: Hello Garf,  i need to combine two executable images into a single one. also i need to do DDR3 partition via software so that each core runs on different sections. how can i achieve this in linux source code? thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't help you on this kind of subject, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the paper by Nett/Schneider?

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tillmann_Nett/publication/257958037_Running_Linux_and_AUTOSAR_side_by_side/links/02e7e5267b740f33ca000000.pdf

Another hint is to look up [OpenAMP](http://www.multicore-association.org/workgroup/oamp.php) and their respective drivers.

Which AUTOSAR are you planning to deploy?

Comment: Hello Ludwig, Thanks for the link. my work is quite similar to this.!!   my deployment is on AUTOSAR MICROSAR OS .